# In my implementation I want to have different return type of the method

Tags: java

I have the following problem. I have the interface:

```
public interface Parser {
    public Map<String, List<String>> parse() throws IOException;
}
```

I have two implementations:

```
public class RacerInfoParser implements Parser{

    private final Path path;

public RacerInfoParser(Path path) {
    this.path = path;   
}

@Override
public Map <String, List<String>> parse() throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String>lines = Files.lines(path)){
        
        Map <Object, Object> map = lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                string -> string.substring(0,3),
                string -> Arrays.asList(string.substring(4).split("_"))));
        
        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>((Map) map);
        return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TimeParser implements Parser {

    private final Path path;

public TimeParser(Path path) {
    this.path = path;   
}


@Override
public Map <String, List<String>> parse() throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String>lines = Files.lines(path)){
        
        Map <Object, Object> map = lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                string -> string.substring(0,3),
                string -> Arrays.asList(string.substring(3).split("_"))));
        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>((Map) map);
    return result;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to change the code and the return type of TimeParser so that it returns the result of type `Map<String, List <LocalTime>`. I have read that in order to have a different type I need to have a sub-class of the parent type, but I don't understand how to do it in my case.

P.S. I know that `Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>((Map) map);` is a bad code, but I don't know yet how to properly convert `Map<Object, Object` to `Map<String, List<String>>`. If you have any suggestions I will be glad to listen to them:).

P.S.S. I use these two implementations because I beleive they do the same thing: parse text from log and txt files:

```
    public class RacerBuilder {
        public List<Racer> buildRacers () throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    
            Parser racerInfoParser = new RacerInfoParser(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader()
                      .getResource("abbreviations.txt").toURI()));
            Parser startTimeParser = new TimeParser(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader()
                      .getResource("start.log").toURI()));
            Parser endTimeParser = new TimeParser(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader()
                      .getResource("end.log").toURI()));
            
            Map<String, List<String>> racerInfoMap = racerInfoParser.parse();
            Map<String, List<String>> startTimeMap = startTimeParser.parse();
            Map<String, List<String>> endTimeMap = endTimeParser.parse();
    
            return racerInfoMap.keySet().stream()
                    .map(i -> new Racer (i,
                            racerInfoMap.get(i).get(0),
                            racerInfoMap.get(i).get(1),
                            startTimeMap.get(i).get(1),
                            endTimeMap.get(i).get(1),
                            endTimeMap.get(i).get(0)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());  
           }
}
```

Racer class now has several fields, all of them are Strings. I want it to have 2 fields of type LocalTime.

Comment: Make your parser a _generic_ interface: `public interface Parser<T> { ... }` with a method `Map<String, List<T>> parse()`.

Comment: Also. `Map <String, List<String>>` looks complicated for a return type. Possible you are missing domain insight. The `Map <String, List<T>>` may itself be a new class.

Comment: Could you please think/add to the question code that shows how do you plan to use the fact that these two classes implement the same interface `Parser`. With the different return types what is the advantage of being the member of the same hierarchy?

Comment: @MarkBramnik, I edited my question a bit, now I hope it's a bit clearer.

Comment: @IceTeaGreen what you mean by the last line and let's close the question if you are satisfied with the answer which you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wrap the `Map<String, List<String>>` in a new class with a getter, let's call it `MapAsString`. Make it part of a class hierarchy so you have `class MapAsString extends DataMap`. Next have a new class that is a subclass of `DataMap` called perhaps `MapAsLocalTime` where `MapAsLocalTime extends DataMap`.

Bonus points: make your parent `class DataMap` abstract and provide a single abstract method you must implement. that uses Generics to return a `List<String, T>`. You can have a constructor that takes a `T` (generic type) which defines what type `T` will be at construction time. If this seems too hard, perhaps just have it return anything using the wildcard `?`... so getter returns `List<String, ?>` - here `?` can an object of any type

Answer (score 3):

To accept either :

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

or

```
Map<String, List<LocalTime>>
```

You can use generic in this case, all you need is to use :

```
<T> Map<String, List<T>> parse() throws IOException;
                     ^
```

Also your code can be :

```
return lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
        string -> string.substring(0, 3),
        string -> Arrays.asList(string.substring(4).split("_"))));
```

Or if you want a List of LocalTime, you can parse your String and collect as this:

```
return lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
        string -> string.substring(0, 3),
        string -> Arrays.stream(string.substring(4).split("_"))
        .map(LocalTime::parse) // or you can use a Date time formatter
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You don't need to cast with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics T. Like this way

```
interface Parser<T> {
    public Map<String, List<T>> parse() throws IOException;
}

class RacerInfoParser implements Parser<String>{

    private final Path path;

    public RacerInfoParser(Path path) {
        this.path = path;   
    }
    
    @Override
    public Map <String, List<String>> parse() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String>lines = Files.lines(path)){
            
            Map <String,  List<String>> map = lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    string -> string.substring(0,3),
                    string -> Arrays.asList(string.substring(4).split("_"))));
            return map;
            }
        }
    }

class TimeParser implements Parser<LocalTime> {

    private final Path path;

public TimeParser(Path path) {
    this.path = path;   
}


@Override
public Map <String, List<LocalTime>> parse() throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String>lines = Files.lines(path)){
        
        Map<String, List<LocalTime>> result = lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                string -> string.substring(0,3),
                string -> Arrays.stream(string.substring(4).split("_"))
                .map(LocalTime::parse)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ));
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```